# bootstrap style datable() for bokeh dashboard

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bokeh

I'm implementing a dashboard using bokeh & Flask. I'm using the DataTable() method, which works.

This is the datatable example from bokeh:

```
from datetime import date
from random import randint
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, vform
output_file("data_table.html")

data = dict(
    dates=[date(2014, 3, i+1) for i in range(10)],
    downloads=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
)
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

columns = [
    TableColumn(field="dates", title="Date", formatter=DateFormatter()),
    TableColumn(field="downloads", title="Downloads"),
]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

show(vform(data_table))
```

The result looks like this

bokeh datable:
[image]

While this is ok, it's a bit disappointing for someone familiar with the datatables one gets with shiny R (see picture below - looking a lot better with a lot more functionalities (e.g. search, pagination)!). I was hoping it would be possible to implement similar bootstrap style datable in bokeh. Has anybody managed to get the datatable look better under bokeh?

Shiny bootstrap datable:
[image]

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Hi vanburen, I have added the standard example from the bokeh documentation if that helps. This is a generic question. I'm looking for a nicer implementation of datatables in bokeh. I'm not sure it exists.

Comment: Ever find a solution vanburen?